# Remove a column from a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my table the td's in first row contains an image. When I click the image I want to delete the entire columns (td's) below the image using jQuery.

How can I do this?

```
<table  border="1" >  
        <tr>
        <td >
        <img  src="addButton.jpg" id='addButton' />
        </td> 
        <td >
        <img  src="addButton.jpg" id='addButton' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td >Result1
        </td> 
        <td >Result2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td >Result1
        </td> 
        <td >Result2>/td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: what you have tried?please share your HTML..

Comment: there are multiple ways of doing this, but rly you have no code to show, anything you tried? We're here to help, not to do all the work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One generic way I can think of.

```
$("td img").click(function() {
    var $td = $(this).closest("td");
    var index = $td.index() + 1;
    $td.closest("table").find("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").remove();
});​
```

Comment: Could be: $td.closest("table").eq($td.index()).remove();  without using temp var index

Answer (score 1):

Give your td the same class names that are not applied anywhere else.
then after

```
$(image).Click(function(){
     $('.classname').remove();
});
```